# Node-Sass includes the @use directive when compiling

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass, node-sass

I'm new to sass in general and am using gulp to watch my directory. However I realized that when my CSS Compiles from SASS it includes the @use directive at the top. For instance where I use sass:map this is brought over in the final file. I'm aware that it may just be of nuisance value right now. But wondering how to have them excluded.

Here is the gulpfile that I use for watching/compiling

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var sass = require("gulp-sass");
var sassGlobbing = require("gulp-sass-glob");
sass.compiler = require("node-sass");


var paths = {
    styles:{
        src:"src/scss/**/*.scss",
        dest: "assets/css/",
        index: "src/scss/styles.scss"
    }
}


gulp.task("sass", function(){
    return gulp
        .src(paths.styles.index)
        .pipe(sassGlobbing())
        .pipe(sass().on("error", sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.dest))
})

gulp.task("watch", function(){
    gulp.watch(paths.styles.src, gulp.series("sass"))
})
```

Comment: Hi, I am not sure, but I think I have the same. I am trying to use the new '@use' instead of '@import', but that does not seem to work with gulp-sass. At the moment gulp-sass is not maintained very well. Maybe that is the reason, but I am not sure yet.

Comment: I just found: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2886 where it says that @use is not yet supported

Comment: Is there any reason to need `node-sass`? the doc's clearly say you can just use `sass` instead. https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass

Answer (score 1):

According to this and I am just copying some lines from there
https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import#importing-css

"Note that only Dart Sass currently supports @use. Users of other implementations must use the @import rule instead.)"